# Difference between 지르기 and 때리기

Tags: vocabulary, difference

Here's another question from my study of "The Art of Kyuki-Do". The book refers to some techniques as "chirugi" (which I assume to be "지르기"), and others as "darigi" (which, from context, I assume to be "때리기"). Some examples:

- "knifehand strike" - 손칼 때리기
- "front punch" - 앞 주먹 지르기
- "palm-heel strike" - 산바닥 지르기
- "elbow strike" - 팔꿈치 때리기
- "hammerfist strike" - 매주먹 때리기
- "spearhand strike" - 손끝 지르기
- "knee strike" - 무릎 지르기

My question is: what is the difference between 지르기 and 때리기? The dictionary I have suggests similar meanings--are they interchangeable? Or is there a subtle semantic difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know martial arts, so I can only explain the ordinary meaning of these words, but they are different.

"때리다(때리기)" is to beat/punch/slap someone/something. "지르다(지르기)" is to *thrust* something: it is related to words like "찌르다" (poke) or "내지르다" (thrust forward).

So (I guess) an action named with "지르기" would naturally involve thrusting your body part toward a target.